# Insert fk at the same time as attributes are added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

So im looking to improve my code abit. I currently have two models and two tables that are connected fk and pk.

I want to insert new attributes into my two tables, but in that same instant, i want to set the fk in my db called `USERS`.

Currently i cant find another way other than this:

```
using (db)
{
    var encryptedPassword = PasswordStorage.CreateHash(model.Users.PASSWORD);
    var user = db.USERS.Create();
    user.EMAIL = model.Users.EMAIL;
    user.PASSWORD = encryptedPassword;
    user.NAME = model.Users.NAME;
    db.USERS.Add(user);

    var place = db.PLACES.Create();
    place.CITY = model.Places.CITY;
    place.PLACE_NAME = model.Places.PLACE_NAME;
    place.POSTAL = model.Places.POSTAL;
    place.STREET = model.Places.STREET;
    place.STREET_NO = model.Places.STREET_NO;
    db.PLACES.Add(place);

    db.SaveChanges();

    var placesId = db.USERS.Where(u => u.EMAIL == model.Users.EMAIL).Select(u => u.PLACES_ID).Single();
    placesId = db.PLACES.Where(u => u.PLACE_NAME == model.Places.PLACE_NAME).Select(u => u.id).Single();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

So after the first `db.SaveChanges();` i go in and set my foreign constraint, and i once again save my changes.. For me, this seems very counterintuitive, and i therefore ask you, because i believe there is a smarter way to do this?

Comment: can you show model?

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand your code. What should the second SaveChanges do? After the first SaveChanges you read the placesId, then you overwrite it (without using it before) and then you dont use placesId (so you just wasting time). At the end you call the second SaveChanges (that does nothing because nothing changed). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) i.e. `System.Data.Entity.Migrations;`

```
namespace MigrationsDemo.Migrations
    {
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class AddFK : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddFK(..);
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            RemoveFK(..);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since its looks like `one to one` relationship then i assume you must have `USERS User` in `place` model so you can try this

```
   var encryptedPassword = PasswordStorage.CreateHash(model.Users.PASSWORD);
    var user = db.USERS.Create();
    user.EMAIL = model.Users.EMAIL;
    user.PASSWORD = encryptedPassword;
    user.NAME = model.Users.NAME;

    var place = db.PLACES.Create();
    place.CITY = model.Places.CITY;
    place.PLACE_NAME = model.Places.PLACE_NAME;
    place.POSTAL = model.Places.POSTAL;
    place.STREET = model.Places.STREET;
    place.STREET_NO = model.Places.STREET_NO;
    place.User=user;
    db.PLACES.Add(place);
```