# C# How to deploy/create setup for VS application with localdb?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, localdb

Im trying to deploy application application with localdb. What I currently achieved is that I created mdf file from my localdb and add it to setup project (Visual Studio Installer). I modified connection of mdf file to localdb database. What I'm worried about this solution, when I'll edit database and install updates on client PC, if the data from mdf file will be lost. Is there a better way how to deploy or is this method valid?

Problem with this method is that I cant reach my stored procedure, even server explorer shows them.

Using VS 2015, SQL Server 2016 and EF 6 in my app.

Connection string, first one was initial one, connecting right to localdb, second one is connecting to mdf file. First one si working correctly, but only on dev machine, second one is having problems.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MSDBContext" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=MSDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="MSDBContextFile" connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\MSDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: show us your code including your connection strings please

Comment: you can refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx and this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799540/insert-fk-at-the-same-time-as-attributes-are-added/42801431#42801431

Comment: You will most probably end up installing sqlserver on client machine.

Comment: I should mention that I started with Database First approach. And then EF generates me DBContext. 
Installing SQLServer on client machine is not that big problem, but problem is, how should I create database here.

Comment: Respectively, I used Code First approach on existing database - [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/data/jj200620) .

Comment: if use db first, restore/attach/tsql will do. Code First can also create database.

Comment: What do you mean by restore and attach exactly? but nto sure which one "First" is this. I created sql server and generate from it classes and context, but in the link i send, it said its Code First Approach, so I'm not sure.